# Escape < and > in sed/shell

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

How do I escape '<' and '>' character in sed.

I have some xml files which needs some text between the tags to be replaced. How do I escape the '>' and '<' characters.

The problem with > and < is it has special meaning in the shell to redirect the output to a file. So backslash doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Found out by myself. Use quotes.

```
$ sed -i "s/>foo</>bar</g" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape them with backslash

Answer (score 0):

Just put a backslash before them or enclose them in single or double quotes.  On second thought, your question I think needs to be more clear.  Are you trying to use sed to process an XML file and you want to get what's between a tag?  Then you want:

```
sed -re 's@(<TAG.*?>).*?(</TAG>)@\1hi\2@' test.xml
```

Comment: I dont want to process the xml file. Just replace some text between the <tag>foobar</tag>. Anyway thanks.